# SVN:All the model types involved in this synchronization are disabled

Tags: eclipse, svn

I imported the source code into Eclipse Java project. But while doing "team synchronization" with "SVN" I got below error:

> All the model types involved in this synchronization are disabled which means there are no element to display

I am not able to synchronize with the SVN. Could you please tell me why this problem comes and how to solve it?

Comment: Does `svn update` from console (if you have any) in your project root dir works ?

Answer (score 5):

Try right-clicking your project -> Team -> Share Project. The plugin will see the local SVN metadata and ask you if you'd like to reuse it (or drop it). Click Finish, and you should be all set.

Comment: Worked great for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is, you checked out the projects with another tool outside Eclipse which is SVN 1.7 compliant (for example the new Tortoise SVN 1.7) and you try to synchronize an Eclipse where you installed Subversive plugin. Subversive plugin is only compatible until SVN 1.6. SVN 1.7 has a new directory structure (there is only one hidden `.svn` file in the folder above all the projects, instead of one `.svn` folder in every project subfolder).

That's why apparently they are not compatible. The error message is not helpful, I agree.
In this case, if you don't want to check out the projects again through eclipse, the only thing you can do is:

- uninstall Tortoise 1.7
- install 1.6
- delete the projects
- check them out again through tortoise 1.6
- open Eclipse

Then you have to do nothing, it will automatically synchronize your projects if you configured the repositories.